# Entity Framework migration from MySQL to SQL Server and the Table names missing "dbo"

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am maintaining an existing (and working) C# project which uses `Entity Framewwork 6` to do the ORM. Now I need to migrate the database from `MySQL` to `SQL Server`. So far I have been able to make the program compile by modifying the `.edmx` file (For example, I changed the `Provider` from `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` to `System.Data.SqlClient` and `ProviderManifestToken` from `5.6` to `2008`. Also I needed to change some data types in the ssdl content, for example from double to float).

Now when I run a simple `LINQ` query against the `ObjectContext`-derived context like this:

```
var query = from data in context.user select data;
var users = query.ToArray();
```

It gives me the exception "Invalid object name 'MYDBNAME.user'."

Apparently a ".dbo" is missing, i.e., the translated SQL query should be

```
select * from MYDBNAME.dbo.user
```

instead of

```
select * from MYDBNAME.user
```

But I am not sure how I can instruct EF to add the ".dbo". Is there some configuration/option to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple and easy approach You have to follow the below steps I hope it will work in your case.

1. You have to build all your schema in MSSQL Server from that MYSQL
2. Once you have completed your Database Schema in MSSQL Server
3. Then you have to follow the database first approach in Entity Framework and It will automatically build all you models and DB context from the database.
4. How to generate  DB models and context (Database First Approach) [Data Base First EF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application)
5. Then You will be able to apply Linq on the database and queries. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Like I mentioned this is an existing project so I have a couple existing class files besides the model classes. For example, I have a DatabaseAccessHelper class and a DatabaseModelExtension class (both are static classes). Other than these two files, the only EF-related files are the .edmx file and the generated .Designer.cs file.

Comment: The reason I didn't use database first approach to do thing all over again is because I am afraid there might be some conflicts between the newly generated fiels and the existing files. So I tend to modify files as few as possible. BTW since I don't have a .tt file in this project, I am guessing the project was created using model first. In this scenario how do you suggest?

Comment: Add a new folder in your project and Generate all your models again from the MSSQL server using the database first approach as you have to do one way or the other way. I know you do not want to repeat your self But According to your scenario, It can be the easiest solution. Then you do not need the extra helper static classes. You can directly apply linq over it.

Comment: If I discard the help static classes, I would have to change a lot because these two static classes are used in a lot of places. Repeating myself is not the biggest problem to me. Getting lost between the EF-generated code and the (existing) upper layer code which are using EF context is. But I guess I get your point. I'll see if I can do a database first approach and still get the upper layer code with it.

Comment: Yes, exactly you have to modify. Why not separate your data access layer?